# Why is this version of Equals called?

Tags: c#, .net, assert, equals-operator

Consider the following excerpt from a class **Matrix**.

```
// Both functions below are instance methods of a class Matrix

public bool Equals(Matrix m)
{
    if(m == null || this.RowDim != m.RowDim || this.ColDim != m.ColDim)
        return false;

    for(int i = 0; i < this.RowDim; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < this.ColDim; ++j)
        {
            if(System.Math.Abs(this.rows[i][j] - m.rows[i][j]) > 1E-10)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Overrides System.Object.Equals(object)
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if(!(obj is Matrix))
        throw new InvalidCastException("Cannot cast object instance to instance of type Matrix.");
    return this.Equals((Matrix)obj);
}
```

**Question 1:** Given the above, shouldn't the function

```
public bool Equals(Matrix m)
```

be called directly when we compare against an object which is of type Matrix?
The "most-derived" version of an overloaded function should apply? (Here I mean Matrix is a descendant of Object).
This indeed seems to be the case:

```
// m and m2 are instances of class Matrix
m.Equals(m2); // Calls Equals(Matrix)
m.Equals(new object()); // Calls Equals(object)
```

So I sort of verify my own question with this simple test.

**Question 2:**
However, I have a unit test which looks as

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Matrix_Equals()
{
    RL.Utility.Math.Matrix m = new RL.Utility.Math.Matrix(new double[,] { { 1.2, 3.2 }, { 4.5, 7.8 }, { 5.66, -19.2 } });
    RL.Utility.Math.Matrix m2 = new RL.Utility.Math.Matrix(new double[,] { { 1.2, 3.2 }, { 4.5, 7.8 }, { 5.66, -19.2 } });
    Assert.AreEqual<RL.Utility.Math.Matrix>(m, m2); // Equals(object) is called
}
```

Why is

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
```

called and not

```
public bool Equals(Matrix m)
```

? I can understand why if I had used the non-generic version of

```
Assert.AreEquals
```

because its parameters are of type **Object**. But I use the generic version in which I specify the type to be Matrix:

```
Assert.AreEqual<Matrix>
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243427.aspx) says

> Verifies that two specified generic type data are equal by using the **equality operator**. The assertion fails if they are not equal.

What exactly do they mean by "equality operator"? They can't mean

```
operator==
```

because that would be reference equality for class types, which defeats the purpose. So what's left, calling Equals. This seems to resolve to the overriden version. Why?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: When you call equals, you're actually calling object.Equals() so if you have overridden it, that implementation is called

Comment: FWIW, [here's the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Standard/Debug.cs,db4dbeaef3d029bf,references) for the `AreEqual<T>` method, showing it's calling `.Equals`, and not using `operator==`.

Comment: [Object.Equals Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Object.Equals is not the same as [System.Object.ReferenceEquals()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Phate01 Yes, well, when I explicitly call Equals with an argument of type Matrix my "own version" (i.e. not the overriden one) gets called. But in the Assert method (which also does expected.Equals(actual)) the function call is resolved to the overriden version, even though I have specified the type parameter of the generic Assert method to be Matrix.

Comment: That's why the `Assert<T>` is generic. At compile time, the compiler cannot know about your implementation, it only sees the base class (object) methods, since `T` is taken as a generic object

Comment: This question already has an answer here:
Why “Equals” method resolution with generics differs from explicit calls    This answered my question. "It's because you havent told the generic method that the type implements IEquatable<T>.

Comment: @Phate01 Yeah, but I thought the function called would be resolved at runtime?

Comment: That's not possible because it's not an override. Besides, try to look at the duplicated link to see a way to fix this (but not in `AreEquals`)

Comment: @jensa: There are two steps to resolution of a virtual function overload.  One is picking which virtual slot matches best.  This is performed at compile time.  The other is looking up the function in that virtual slot corresponding to the runtime type of the object.  In this case, when `AreEquals` is compiled, the compiler only knows about the single virtual slot that exists in `object`, the one accepting a parameter of type `object`.  So it emits a `virtcall` instruction, specifying that slot.  At runtime, your `override` is found in that slot, and called.  But the overload is not considered.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hm, this works differently than in for example C++? In C++, I can create a class with a function Foo, then make a function which takes an argumenet of type T (template<typename T> void printFoo(T& t) {t.Foo();}) and this works fine! The compiler manages to resolve at compile time that the function printFoo is called with a type which supports the Foo method.

Comment: That's because C++ has templates, C# does not. Consider that in C# `void MyMethod<T>(T thing){thing.fsdfasdfsaddsa();}` won't compile, because it won't know what `.fsdfasdfsaddsa()` is meant to be. In C++ that's fine until you try to actually use it.

Comment: (And actually, expecting the `Equals()` override to be called is much the same as expecting `fsdfasdfsaddsa()` to be allowed, since at the level of matching up method calls with the method that is called, there's nothing at all the same in `object.Equals()` and `IEquatable<T>.Equals()`

Comment: @jensa: C++ templates are duck-typed, the compiler re-compiles the template code after it knows the template arguments.  .NET generics work differently, the generic parameters can change at runtime, and in fact all reference types share the same JITted machine code for a generic function.

Comment: I see, it seems I was confused by "equating" C++ templates with C# generics. This sentence ".NET generics work differently, the generic parameters can change at runtime," justifies that C# generic methods have to work the way they do, i.e. that the compiler have to know that the type in fact supports its own Equals method (by using where T : IEquatable<T>).